# php array display

Tags: search

```
$a = array(array( 'dates' => '12-11-13',
    'customer' => 'ann',
    'place' => 'EKM'),array('dates' => '12-11-13',
    'customer' => 'annex',
    'place' => 'KLM'),array('dates' => '13-11-13',
    'customer' => 'anna',
    'place' => 'PTA')
  );
```

how to this array displayed following format using PHP

```
   dates:12-11-13
   customer:ann
   place:EKM
   customer:annex
   place:KLM

   dates:13-11-13
   customer:anna
   place:PTA
```

Comment: Looks like a definition list to me. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <?php
        $a = array(array( 'dates' => '12-11-13',
            'customer' => 'ann',
            'place' => 'EKM'),array('dates' => '12-11-13',
            'customer' => 'annex',
            'place' => 'KLM'),array('dates' => '13-11-13',
            'customer' => 'anna',
            'place' => 'PTA')
          );

        $result = array(); //Your minimized array
             foreach($a as $value)
             {
               $dates = $value['dates'];
               if(isset($result[$dates]))
                $index = ((count($result[$dates]) - 1) / 2) + 1;
            else
                $index = 1;

               $result[$dates]['dates'] = $dates;
               $result[$dates]['customer' . $index] = $value['customer']; 
               $result[$dates]['place' . $index] = $value['place'];  


        }
        $result = array_values($result);
        for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
        {
        foreach($result[$i] as $r1)
        {

            $r2[$i][]=$r1;
        }   
        ?>
        <?php echo 'dates:'.$r2[$i][0].'</br>';?>
            <?php
        if(count($r2[$i])>3)
        {
        ?>    


         <?php

        $k=count($r2[$i]);
            for($j=1;$j<$k;$j++)
            {
        ?>
            <?php echo 'customer:'.$r2[$i][$j].'</br>';?>
             <?php echo 'place:'.$r2[$i][$j+1].'</br>';?>
            </tr>

        <?php
        $j=$j+1;
            }
            echo '</br>';
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <?php echo 'customer:'. $r2[$i][1].'</br>';?>
           <?php echo 'place:'.$r2[$i][2].'</br></br>';?>


             <?php

        }
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something [like this](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/x80-b4c):

```
$a = array(array( 'dates' => '12-11-13',
    'customer' => 'ann',
    'place' => 'EKM'),array('dates' => '12-11-13',
    'customer' => 'annex',
    'place' => 'KLM'),array('dates' => '13-11-13',
    'customer' => 'anna',
    'place' => 'PTA')
  );

foreach ($a as $row) {
 foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
   echo "$k:$v<br/>";
 }
  echo "<br/>";
}
```